# Implement main loop in haskell using mutable state

Tags: loops, haskell, program-entry-point

I'm trying to implement a main loop of sorts in Haskell, in C I would write it like this:

```
EntityInteraction *frame(Entity *eList, EntityInteraction *iList) {
    parseInteractions(eList, iList);
    return simulateEntities(eList);
}

int main() {
    Entity eList[] = {...}
    EntityInteraction *iList = NULL;
    while(true) {
        iList = frame(eList, iList);
    }
}
```

So I attempted to replicate this in haskell by making frame a recursive function:

```
frame :: [Entity] -> [EntityInteraction] -> IO ()
frame eList iList = do
    frame (parseInteractions iList eList) (simulateEntities eList)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let entList = [...]
    frame entList []
```

But this just results in a stack overflow as expected, so my question is what is the propper way to do a main loop in haskell that uses mutable state?

(I've been programming in C as a hobby for 4 years and I'm just starting to learn haskell)

Comment: Tail recursion such as this shouldn't result in a stack overflow. Maybe you `elist` or `ilist` just grows too big at some point? Also, how did you compile your program? Try with `ghc -O2` just to make sure.

Comment: eList, and iList never gets added to. I tried with the -O2 switch and it still gives me the message: "main: out of memory"

Comment: Maybe you can provide a complete, compilable, minimal example. I just tried `main = frame` ; `frame = return () >> frame`, and while this obviously burns the cpu, it happily runs forever in constant space (using 800k memory).

Comment: The entire source code is here: http://pastebin.com/FrnyLb4e it's meant to be a functionally pure entity system, at the moment it does nothing though

Comment: The trouble is you are just recursing forever without ever outputting ("observing") anything.  Add a `print` before the recursive call to `frame`, and you'll see that it's doing just fine.  (Laziness does change the nature of "mutable" state -- i.e. you are building up thunks rather than computing anything -- but you are on the right track, and observing the results will help)

Comment: Luqui is right. Lazy evaluation means not doing any work until you have to. If you never output anything, the recursive calls build up without resolving, whereas if they're requied for something, they'll get calculated down into constant space. The act of observing it actually changes it from uncalculated to calculated. I've just been reading about quantum entanglement this morning, and hadn't noticed the conceptual link with lazy evaluation before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an interesting phenomenon which only hits you in this empty example.

First, here is a minimal example:

```
frame :: [a] -> IO ()
frame eList = do    
    frame (id eList) 

main :: IO ()
main = do        
    frame []
```

If I run this with `runghc`, I get an out of memory error. However, either of these works:
(if you compile them with ghc -O2, you might actually get the output `<<loop>>` and the program terminating. `runghc` doesn't detect the loop though and you can see the program running in constant space.)

A)

```
frame :: [a] -> IO ()
frame eList = do   
    frame eList

main :: IO ()
main = do        
    frame []
```

B)

```
frame :: [a] -> IO ()
frame eList = do    
    print eList
    frame (id eList) 

main :: IO ()
main = do        
    frame []
```

C)

```
frame :: [a] -> IO ()
frame eList = do   
    eList `seq` frame (id eList) 

main :: IO ()
main = do        
    frame []
```

What's the reason for this? Well, tail recursion *per se* is not the problem. There is no stack overflow, but an out of memory error. Why, if your lists are not actually changed with every loop iteration?

Well, they are! The function application itself builds up unevaluated thunks because you are never using the values! In all of the working examples, the only difference is that the values are actually evaluated and the thunks removed.

So the sequence of functions calls looks something like this in the erronous example:

```
frame []
frame (id [])
frame (id (id []))
frame (id (id (id []))) -- the argument takes more memory with every iteration
...
```

But like this in the working examples:

```
frame []
frame []
frame []
frame []
frame []
frame []                -- argument stays the same as 'id' is evaluated away.
```

Even though the thunks are not too expensive for themselves, in an infinite loop they will inevitable eat up all your memory, given enough time.

Answer (score 0):

You need this, I think:

```
frame :: [Entity] -> [EntityInteraction] -> IO ()
frame eList iList = do
    parseInteractions iList eList
    simulateEntities eList

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let entList = [...]
    forever $ frame entList []
```

Though it seems not to make much sense, for example, `elist` is always the empty list and so could be omitted.
But if `parseInteractions` in your C solution produces/fills `eList`, then probably

```
eList <- parseInteractions iList
```

In this case, the question is if `parseInteractions` really needs to do IO?